# Download file from Sharepoint via Visual Basic Script

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript

I am trying to download a file from sharepoint via VBScript.

Unfortunately i get the following errormessage after downloading the Excel- File:

"Excel cannot open the file ' xxxxx.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"

My code snipped is the following:

```
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/teams/xxxxx/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B5AA396CB-4711-4E73-AEC5-3CB8B6E174D3%7D&file=xxxx%20Automation%xxxx.xlsx&wdOrigin=OFFICECOM-WEB.START.REC&action=default&mobileredirect=true", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "c:\temp\TestNow.xlsx", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

Comment: I would imagine that because you are not authenticating in anyway the response you are receiving is a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` which will be HTML and not a valid XLSX file. Try opening the file with `notepad.exe` or some other text editor and see what the file contains.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your assumption is currect. Its actually a HTML.

<html><head><title>Working...</title></head><body>

<form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://company.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx"><input type="hidden" name="code". 


Could you kindly help me with a possible fix aswell?

Comment: The easiest way, to get files out of the SharePoint is via the content database if you have access to that. Trying to provide authentication through VBScript to SharePoint to download a file can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks very much. Any ideas how to implement this download in any workflow? Hasn't to be VBScript. Could also be ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

The approach isn't wrong but when dealing with downloads from a URL you should always check the Response Status Code to see if it is valid before continuing.

After calling `Send()` always surround the response in a conditional statement like this;

```
If xHttp.Status = 200 Then 'Expecting a HTTP 200 OK response
    With bStrm
        .Type = 1 '//binary
        .Open
        .Write xHttp.responseBody
        .SaveToFile "c:\temp\TestNow.xlsx", 2 '//overwrite
    End With
Else
    'Check the response body for details of the error.
    MsgBox("Unexpected response: " & xHttp.Status & " - " & xHttp.StatusText, 48, "Error")
End If
```

Because you are trying to download from a SharePoint site the likelihood is the request is failing and returning an `HTTP 403 Forbidden` for not providing any authentication.

Comment: While connecting to SPO (any `*.sharepoint.com` address will be SharePoint Online) these days requires modern authentication in the form of a username and password, SPO sites/hubs *can* be configured to allow guest/anonymous access. Hard to say without more info from OP.